# interrupt handling in c using PIC16F84 microcontroller

Tags: c

i am implementing an fsm for my timer switch.so right now i am developing a function for interrupt ISR function so as to keep track of time and to avoid overflows starting right when the timer is switched on.

here is what i already have

```
unsigned char   pulses;
interrupt isr(void)
{
    if(T0IF) {
        ++pulses;                    // increment pulses
        T0IF=0;                      // reset TMR0 flag
    }
}
```

i need help in setting the clock source and the prescalar in the program and how to preload it with a new start value just before clearing the TOIF.

the PIC16F84 user manual says:TMR0 overflow interrupt flags are contained in
the INTCON register.The interrupt control register (INTCON) records
individual interrupt requests in flag bits.

An overflow (FFh - 00h) in TMR0 will set flag bit T0IF
(INTCON<2>). The interrupt can be enabled/disabled
by setting/clearing enable bit T0IE (INTCON<5>)

below is the frame-code i am working on, using MPLAB IDEv8.92 and with HCPIC-picc-v9.83
THANKS.please let me know if i need to specify more on the question.

```
#include <htc.h>
#include "timer.h"
#ifdef XT
        __CONFIG(XT&PWRTEN&WDTDIS);             // config XT
#else
    __CONFIG(0x3ff1);                       // config XT
    #define OPTION OPTION_REG
#endif

bit GeyserFlag;

extern void cput(unsigned char c);
extern void scroll(const char *mess, unsigned char ntimes);
extern void display(const char *message);
extern void clrscr(void);
extern char choice(const char *const *menu);
extern char getch(void);
extern void delay(unsigned char time); 
extern char choice(const char *const *fmenu);
extern char sbuf[15];
extern char line[13];
extern unsigned char pulses;

const char *const menu1[]={
       "--SET TIME--",
       "--VIEW TIME--",0};

void scrolling()
{
 printf("make a choice by pressing select");
}
void do_nothing()
{
 printf("Dont bother");
}
void present_choice_on_screen()
{
 printf("present choice on screen");
}
void perform_the_choice()
{
 printf("do menu[j] ");
}

main()
{
  INTCON=0x20;      // TMR0 allowed to interrupt
    OPTION=0x07;// prescaler 1:128 to TMR0, enable     pullup resistors on PORTA
TRISB=0x00;                 // RB7 is input RB6:RB0 are inputs
TRISA=0x07;                 // port A RA2:RA0 input
pulses=0;
GIE=1;                      // enable all interrputs
relayoff();
RW0_HIGH(); RW1_HIGH(); // hold WR high to prevent writing to display
TRISA=0x00;

char GeyserOffTime[4];
char GeyserOnTime[4];
char CurrentTime[4];

if(GeyserFlag)
   {
    if(strcmp(GeyserOffTime, CurrentTime) != 0);//check if it is time to turn OFF
        {
            GeyserFlag = 0;
            relayoff();
        }//end if

}//end if

else
{ //if Flag is off: ie Geyser is OFF
    if(strcmp(GeyserOnTime, CurrentTime) != 0);//check if it is time to turn it ON
        {
            relayon();
            GeyserFlag = 1;

        }//end if
}//end else


unsigned char   i,j;
int State,e;
  enum State {state_0,state_1,state_2};
  enum Event {mode,select,set};


State  = state_0;

  switch(State)
 {
  case state_0:
   switch(e)
    {
      case select:
     {
      do_nothing();
      break;
      }
    case set:
     {
      do_nothing();
      break;
     }
    case mode:
     {
     State = state_1; 
     scrolling();
      break;
     }
   }
   break;

 case state_1:
   switch(e)
    {
      case select:
     {
      State = state_2;
      present_choice_on_screen();
      break;
     }
    case set:
     {
      do_nothing();
      break;
      }
    case mode:
     {
      do_nothing();
      break;
      }
    }
    break;

 case 2:
   switch(e)
    {
      case select:
      {
       perform_the_choice();
       break;
        }
      case set:
      {
      do_nothing();
       break;
       }
    case mode:
     {
      do_nothing();
      break;
     }
    }
    break;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Does it not tell you what registers to load with what in the user manual?

Comment: `void scrolling(); {  printf("make a choice by pressing select"); }` is certainly wrong - note the ';' after `scrolling()`.  This mistake exist in a number of places.  Looks like you are trying to define functions _within_ `main()`.